# one-zero to many cascade delete

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, entity-framework-5

I have this model :

```
    public class FileUpload
{
    public int FileUploadId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FileUpload Logo { get; set; }
    public int? LogoId { get; set; }

    public FileUpload Catalog { get; set; }
    public int? CatalogId { get; set; }
}

public class Ads
{
    public int AdsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FileUpload Picture { get; set; }
    public int? PictureId { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ads> Adses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FileUpload> FileUploads { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ads>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.Picture)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.PictureId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
           .HasOptional(a => a.Logo)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(a => a.LogoId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
           .HasOptional(a => a.Catalog)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(a => a.CatalogId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

this code is not working in EF migration!

I want : 
- every company has optional Logo or Catalog and every Ads has optional Picture. 
- the FileUpload record can be deleted directly
- cascade delete

how to do this?!

Comment: Explain what you mean by _not working_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want that a `FileUpload` is deleted by cascading delete when a `Company` or `Ads` is deleted?

This would make no sense because `FileUpload` is the principal in all three relationships and `Company` and `Ads` are the dependents. You cannot cascading delete the principal when a dependent is deleted. It would fail in most cases anyway because in a one-to-many relationship the `FileUpload` could be used by many other companies or ads. If you delete one of them and the `FileUpload` would be deleted by cascading delete you would violate a foreign key constraint for the other companies and ads.

In your model you could only have a cascading delete so that `Company` and `Ads` are deleted when a `FileUpload` is deleted (which sounds strange to me though). Even that would not work with your Fluent mapping because you have configured multiple cascading delete paths from `FileUpload` to `Company` with the two relationships. SQL Server doesn't allow such relationships. You would have to remove at least one cascading delete.

In you model you need to delete the `FileUpload` records manually when a `Company` and `Ads` is deleted *after* your have checked if the `FileUpload` isn't used by another company or ads.

If you know for sure in your business logic that a given `FileUpload` cannot be used by more than one company or ads and that the same `FileUpload` is never used by a company and by an ads, it is getting simpler (example for deleting a company):

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    var company = context.Companies
        .Include(c => c.Logo)
        .Include(c => c.Catalog)
        .Single(c => c.CompanyId == companyIdToDelete);

    if (company.Logo != null)
        context.FileUploads.Remove(company.Logo);

    if (company.Catalog != null && company.Logo != company.Catalog)
        context.FileUploads.Remove(company.Catalog);

    context.Companies.Remove(company);
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot ... i did this in my project but thanx for your good explain:) ... i got it ;)